# Are some tail wheels made out of solid plastic?

Tags: landing-gear, composite-materials

Are any tail wheels on small planes made of hard, rounded, plastic-like material?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE!

Answer (score 23):

You can see that sort of thing on ultralights that land at 25-30 mph where they may use a solid once-piece wheel made of some elastomeric plastic or rubber.  Smaller airplanes however, will use a rubber tire on an aluminum wheel with proper bearings, due to the very high rolling RPM once you are landing above 40 mph (or at least a bushing that can take high speeds and loads).

The smallest ones usually have solid rubber tires and once you get to a certain size, say on airplanes over 1500 lbs or so, they will be pneumatic tires.  For example, an [Aeronca Champ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeronca_Champion) usually has a solid rubber tailwheel, but it's heavier and faster [Citabria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Champion_Citabria) descendant has a pneumatic tailwheel tire.  You can browse typical tailwheel tires [here](https://www.aircraftspruce.com/categories/aircraft_parts/ap/menus/lg/tailwheels.html).

Comment: $1,000+ for a solid rubby wheel on a caster. I should get into the niche aircraft parts business.

Comment: Once the part is "certified", triple the price. The extra money won't go in your pocket; it's eaten up in regulatory compliance costs.   You will notice that the uncertified homebuilt tailwheels are far cheaper because there are no regulatory hoops.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few sailplanes (e.g. Schweizer 2-22, 2-33) are currently equipped with plastic skateboard wheels for tailwheels, even though that may not have been the part that was originally prescribed.